# Send orders from OpenCart to WooCommerce

Tags: php, api, woocommerce, opencart

I am having very specific task that needs to be implemented. I have to import specific orders from one OpenCart shop to another WooCommerce shop. The reason we're doing this is because in the woocommerce shop there are some functionalities that we don't want to implement on the OC and we just want to use the WooCommerce.

One of the options i thought about was to get the orders from the database directly / they are using the same server so that's easy to access /, but I run into an issue trying to pass the Shipping method ( because it comes from the checkout and shows a form in the backend that we need ).

So I am thinking of another way to simulate the process through the WooCommerce REST API, but I am not sure from where to start.. Have someone worked on similar thing, I would appreciate if I get some guidance.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Using the API sounds like the right way to go. But this question is far too broad for anyone to answer here. Read the API docs, try some stuff and when you get stuck on a specific problem I'm sure someone will be able to help you here!

Comment: You are right, thank you. I just wanted to see if someone made something similar so I can find the best way to do it that's why I asked.